# Sonata Admin Bundle - Customise select field display values for nested set

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have an Entity type which uses the nested set extension.  When I am accessing it within the Sonata Admin forms, it just shows up as a basic select box with no distinction between levels.

How can I force each option to be displayed using an additional '-' symbol for its level in order to help identify the nested elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see a way to do this directly in the Sonata Admin Bundle but got around it by editing the model's toString method:

```
public function __toString() {
    return str_repeat('-', $this->lvl).' '.$this->getTitle();
}
```